# How can I use multiple fields in Kibana Pie Charts?

Tags: visualization, kibana

I want to make a pie chart in Kibana that uses two data fields. I want the chart to have only two slices, so for example, I would show myPizzasEaten/totalPizzas (kind of like a progress circle).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44578052/1717396