# Kibana - Pie-Chart with sum over two different fields

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, pie-chart

In an index I have two mappings.

```
"mappings" : {
    "deliveries" : {
        "properties" : {
            "@timestamp":  { "type" : "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd" },
            "receiptName" : { "type" : "text" },
            "amountDelivered" : { "type" : "integer" },
            "amountSold" : { "type" : "integer" },
            "sellingPrice" : { "type" : "float" },
            "earned" : { "type" : "float" }
        }
    },
    "expenses" : {
        "properties" : {
            "@timestamp":  { "type" : "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd" },
            "description": { "type" : "text" },
            "amount": { "type": "float" }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I wanted to create a simple Pie Chart in Kibana for sumarize up `deliveries.earned` and `expenses.amount`.

Is this possible or do I have to switch to an client application? The number of documents (2 or 3 a month) is really to less to start some development here xD

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple [scripted_field through Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html) which maps **amount** and **earned** fields to the same field, called **transaction_amount**.

Painless script:

```
if(doc['earned'].length > 0) { return doc['earned']; } else { return doc['amount']; }
```

Then you can create a *Pie Chart* with *"Slice Size"* configured as the sum of **transaction_amount** and *"Split Slices"* configured as a *Terms Aggregation* on *_type*.

Comment: Can you take a look at this answer again? You're saying the fields will be mapped to transaction_amount, but I don't see this in the code.

Comment: Your right, the actual mapping itself is happening through the kibana UI.